# I have a DF with 2 columns. I wanna do a boolean check on it

Tags: pandas, list, function, dataframe, set

I have a DF that has 3 columns and i wanna perform a Boolean check. The code is shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1':[A,A,A,B,B,C,C,C],
    'Col2':[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7] ,[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7] ]
    'Col3': [[1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7] ,[1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3, 4] ]
})
```

I want a DF that gives me for a unique value of Col1 and if one row of Col2, Col3 are equal, print True, else False.  The result i would like to see is:

```
'Col1' 'Col2'                         'Col3'          'Col4'                               
  A    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]  [1,2,3,4]         False

print(map(type, df['Col2']) == map(type,df['Col3']))
```

This returned me value true, but I want it as a new column Col4 in the df

For multiple codes i tried , I always found errors as `unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: ```df['Col4'] = df['Col2'] == df['Col3']```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply this logic per group of `Col1`, use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df['Col4'] = df.groupby('Col1').apply(lambda x: x['Col2'].eq(x['Col3'])).values

  Col1                                     Col2                                     Col3   Col4
0    A  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]                             [1, 2, 3, 4]  False
1    A  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]   True
2    A  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  False
3    B                          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]                          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   True
4    B                          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]                                [1, 2, 3]  False
5    C                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]   True
6    C                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]                                [1, 2, 3]  False
7    C                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]                             [1, 2, 3, 4]  False
```

Not taking the groups into account, gives same output in this case, using [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)

```
df['Col4'] = df['Col2'].eq(df['Col3'])

  Col1                                     Col2                                     Col3   Col4
0    A  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]                             [1, 2, 3, 4]  False
1    A  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]   True
2    A  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  False
3    B                          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]                          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   True
4    B                          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]                                [1, 2, 3]  False
5    C                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]   True
6    C                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]                                [1, 2, 3]  False
7    C                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]                             [1, 2, 3, 4]  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to Strings to allow the comparison:

```
    df['Col4'] = df.Col2.map(str) == df.Col3.map(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a new way `tuple`

```
df.Col2.map(tuple)==df.Col3.map(tuple)
Out[646]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```